# Four Color Theorem

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have been trying to write a code that would use the four color theorem to color regions defined by an adjacency matrix. An adjacency matrix would look like:

```
    A B C D

A   0 1 0 1
B   1 0 1 0
C   0 1 0 1
D   1 0 1 0
```

So for this example A is not adjacent to itself or C, but it is adjacent to B and D.

The program I am writing has to use recursion and back-tracing to assign 4 colors (or less) to the defined regions.

So far my algorithm is as follows:

```
global int[] colors = <region one color,region two, region three, region four >
public static int color(row,column)
  if out of bounds ??
    loop(!colored)
    {
      case 1: are any adjacent regions this color? assign
      case 2: are any adjacent regions this color? assign.
      case 3: are any adjacent regions this color? assign.
      case 4: are any adjacent regions this color? assign.
      case 5: if nothing found, steal closest (in #) region's color and call method from there
  }
```

But I have a few questions:

1. What would this method return?
2. Would this work and have recursion/backtracing like it should?
3. What would I output if the given row/column are out of bounds?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better tagged with algorithm instead of java, or would be more appropriate for programmers.se?

Comment: I am still rather new to Stack Overflow but my some of my questions are asking about the java part specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudocode looks more like [local search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_%28optimization%29) than recursion/backtracking. The logical return would be `void`, since local search cannot prove the absence of a solution, so failure is indicated by running forever. (The coloring itself, if found, is returned via the global variables.)

Recursion/backtracking would be more like this.

```
boolean extend-coloring(partial-coloring):
    if every vertex has a color, then return true
    let v be a vertex without a color
    for each color c,
        if v has no neighbors of color c,
            apply color c to v in partial-coloring
            if extend-coloring(partial-coloring), then return true
            remove color c from v
    return false
```

The root invocation is `extend-coloring(empty-coloring)`, where `empty-coloring` assigns no vertex a color. The return value indicates whether the attempt to extend the partial coloring succeeded.

Comment: For your code would it apply every color to a vertex then check the remaining ones if it would work? Also would you have to scan each row for neighbors every call?

Comment: @NickMireles Yes to your first question. As to your second, that's sort of an implementation detail. The easiest thing to do would be to rescan every time, yes.

Comment: I was unsure about that, thank you. I just realized that would be, I apologize. Once I have the code completed should I post it here?

Comment: @NickMireles It's up to you.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat O(n!)